# How to check if a component disappears after click using jest & enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme

I have a component,

```
function TestComponent() {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {visible && <Container>
        I'm Visible
        <button onClick={() => setVisible(false)}>
          click to close
        </button>
      </Container>}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

I'm trying to test that on clicking the button the component should be invisible.

And I have following test case to test that,

```
test('Random Test', () => {
  const randomComponent = shallow(<TestComponent />);

  expect(randomComponent.find('Container')).toBeTruthy();
  randomComponent.find('button').simulate('click');
  expect(randomComponent.find('Container')).toBeFalsy();
});
```

Doesnt seem to work,
Getting error,

```
expect(received).toBeFalsy()

Received: {}
```

Any help would be appreciated?
I have a sneaky suspicion that this isnt the way to check if component is hidden. Would also appreciate if anyone could tell a better way.

Update #1:

```
expect(randomComponent.render().text()).toContain('I\'m Visible');
randomComponent.find('button').simulate('click');
expect(randomComponent.render().text()).toContain('');
```

Using the above testcases seem to work. Still looking for a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Since `.find()` will always return an instance of `ShallowWrapper` class even if there is no node matched. See [source code of `.find()`](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/blob/8c55734eb19a2f7555eb3d695ae11401fa1f9847/packages/enzyme/src/ShallowWrapper.js#L1018) and [.wrap()](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/blob/8c55734eb19a2f7555eb3d695ae11401fa1f9847/packages/enzyme/src/ShallowWrapper.js#L1663). It will NOT return a falsy value (`null`, `undefined`), so `.toBeFalsy()` assertion will always fail.

1. Use [.exists([selector]) => Boolean](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/exists.html)

> Returns whether or not any nodes exist in the wrapper. Or, if a selector is passed in, whether that selector has any matches in the wrapper.

```js
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import { TestComponent } from './';

describe('68334346', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const randomComponent = shallow(<TestComponent />);
    expect(randomComponent.find('Container').exists()).toBeTruthy();
    randomComponent.find('button').simulate('click');
    expect(randomComponent.find('Container').exists()).toBeFalsy();
  });
});
```

2. Use [.toHaveLength(number)](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tohavelengthnumber) matcher

```js
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import { TestComponent } from './';

describe('68334346', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const randomComponent = shallow(<TestComponent />);
    expect(randomComponent.find('Container')).toHaveLength(1);
    randomComponent.find('button').simulate('click');
    expect(randomComponent.find('Container')).toHaveLength(0);
  });
});
```